# Passing list of arguments of varying length to scipy.optimize.minimize (understanding the arguments)

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I want to understand the arguments provided to scipy.optimize.minimize. I'm calling my optimization as

```
res = minimize(func, para_init, method= 'SLSQP', constraints=cons)
```

The `para_init` looks like, `[x,y,np.array([a,b,c]),np.array([e,f])]` , and cons is a dictionary of constraints. `func()` takes in all the parameters listed in `para_init` and gives out a scalar object. However i'm facing the following problems:

1) Error: `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence`

2) I want to specify `xtol = 0.001, ftol = 0.001,  bounds = None, jac = None`, if i simply add these line to `minimize()` it complains as `TypeError: minimize() got an unexpected keyword argument 'xtol'`. Also I want to have the following specifications `options = {'maxiter': 100,'disp': True}` but then also i gut similar unexpected keyword error.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: The first error is because you have to supply an initial guess as the second argument. The second error is because `xtol` and `ftol` are not arguments to minimize. `tol` is probably the argument you are looking for there. Overall, read the man page: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html#scipy.optimize.minimize

Comment: I made mistake and I've edited, Mistakenly i was using `args = para_init`, i want `para_init` to be my initial guess and there is no extra argument or args

Answer (score 1):

From http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html:

> **scipy.optimize.minimize(** fun, x0, args=(), method=None, jac=None, hess=None, hessp=None, bounds=None, constraints=(), tol=None, callback=None, options=None **)**

`minimize()` wants two positional arguments: `fun` and `x0`

Moreover, it has no `xtol` or `ftol` keyword argument, but has a `tol` keyword arg (Tolerance for termination).

The `xtol`, `ftol`, `maxfev` are specific to the method used. In particular are specific of the Nelder-Mead method, and not available for the method you are using (SLSQP).

Method-specific options can be supplied through the `options` dict.

Therefore, you should call:

> res = minimize(func, x0, args=para_init, method= 'SLSQP', constraints=cons, bounds=..., jac=..., options={...})

Comment: Thanks, please see the edit in Error1 (there is no args)

Comment: mescalinum, are `xtol` and `ftol` SLSQP options? I don't believe they are.

Comment: indeed they are for Nelder-Mead method. it seems the OP got quite a few things out of order

Answer (score 0):

`minimize` has two required arguments: the function to minimize and an initial guess. You haven't supplied the latter. See [this](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html). Consider calling `scipy.optimize.fmin_slsqp` directly. The [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin_slsqp.html#scipy.optimize.fmin_slsqp) is clearer, because the parameter semantics don't depend on optimization method. In other words, `minimize` calls other functions (e.g. `fmin_slsqp`) by assigning the former's arguments to the latter, which makes `minimize` difficult to document concisely and comprehensively.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll have a look at fmin_slsqp